# How can I show ProgressDialog at the start of the Activity?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-activity, progressdialog

I will open the Activity(name is VideoAcivity). This Activity is doing some video proccess and show the video. I know how to use progress dialog, Already I'm using progressdialog between my activities but i couldn't use progressdialog without `AsyncTask`, `onPreExecute`, `onPostExecute`. I want to show progressdialog when activity started without using `AsyncTask` because i'm using Thread in this Activity.

```
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);
     txtDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     getin = getIntent();
     video = getin.getStringExtra("Video_URL");
     subtitle = getin.getStringExtra("Subtitle_URL");
          mPreview = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
     holder = mPreview.getHolder();
     holder.setFixedSize(800, 480);
     holder.addCallback(this);
     holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);       
     mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
     mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
     mediaController = new MediaController(this);

       } // this is oncrete 
// ---> mediaplyer and mediacontroller codes..

public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
         Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared");
         mediaController.setMediaPlayer(this);
         mediaController.setAnchorView(findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1));

         handler.post(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
             mediaController.setEnabled(true);
             mediaController.show();
           }
         });
       }

Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                // Codes..
        }
            });

         th.start();
         th.join();
```

I tried to add some codes and debugged, whatever i tried, ProgressDialog is not appearing when the activity start. I couldn't find the reason. It is appearing a little time at the end of the proccess. (All Proccess is taking 7-8 seconds, it is appearing only 1 second) Where am i doing wrong ? Where should I add the progress dialog codes? Hope you can help me..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Get progressDialog declared and put this in onCreate method-

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
progressDialog.setMessage("Loding");
progressDialog.show();
progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
```

And when your background task completes -

```
progressDialog.dismiss();
```

---

You need some kinda callback when your thread stops or you complete the task which you were doing in background. In `asynctask` you get `onPostExecute` method and it runs on main UI thread so you can dismiss `progressDialog` or do some other UI stuff. But in case of thread you don't have such method.

You need to identify when thread stops and then use this if you're still in thread-

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but i've already tried this. Still it is appearing just one second. I debugged, progressdialog codes works without problem but meanwhile it is not working. How is it possible i don't understand

Comment: thanks for the edit and information=) but still the same, i put it where the thread finishs nothing changed(showhig only one second,but my proccess is taking 7-8 seconds). My problem is starting the progressDialog, somehow it is starting late.

Comment: Where did you put `progressDialog.show()`: in the beginning, middle, or almost end of a given job/task?

Comment: at the beginig of `onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)` method

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `Thread.join()` method on your worker thread, seemingly from your main thread. This will make your main thread wait until your worker thread has completed. It won't be able to update the UI properly during this time. Android needs the main thread to be free to display the ProgressDialog.

What are you trying to accomplish with `Thread.join()` here? Try to remove it and see what happens.

Comment: I put it because, first `Thread th` should finish its job and then current thread `thread.currentthread` will continue. In `Thread th` i'm downloading subtitle to my sdcard and while it is downloading the subtitle, only `Thread th` must work. Otherwise player is playing without subtitle and it causes error(null error with `player.addtimedtextsource()`. `thread.join()` blocks the current thread until the receiver finishes its execution and dies.

Comment: I put the `ProgressDialog.show` at the begining of the Activity, before new Thread `th.start` and `th.join` works, `ProgressDialog` is already working, but nothing appears. Its not about the `Thread.join()`. Thank you